# Kinect v2 not working on windows 10 (Fan not spanning)

Tags: c#, windows-10, kinect

When I open the "Kinect Configuration Verifier" it says that:

- Supported usb 3.0 detected with unknown bandwidth...
- No Kinect for windows v2 sensor detected

It may be important to say that the kinect's fan is not spanning. Also I am using Kinect for Windows HUB for connecting the device to my computer.

May you please help me how to resolve the problem?

I've already installed the SDK.

Thank you

Comment: Should I do or install any software to turn on the device?

Comment: Try to connect directly to the USB and check if it works. Usually, HUBs limit the bandwidth and that may be the cause of your problem. If that's the case, you will have to buy a better HUB.